# R, create row and give it a name whist assigning data

Tags: r, r-rownames

I would like to know if it is possible with R, to create in one go a row, name it and assign it values.

for example, I have.

This df is named domain
[image: This df is named domain]

and I Have This df is named tactics

[image: This df is named tactics]

and I would like to combine both sort of like this

```
for(aptname in names(result)){
   domain <- t(result[[aptname]][["Domain"]])
   tactics <- t(result[[aptname]][["Tactics"]])
   newdf[nrow[aptname]] <- domain + tactics
}
```

so the final version would look like this

[image]

kind regards,

Comment: Can you just `cbind` them? Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly into a [code block].

Comment: I did cbind them indeed recently yea ^^' sorry i didn't think about it before posting.

Comment: but i am still left with the issue of naming the row

Comment: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/row.names.html or https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/colnames.html ?

Comment: This let me rename manually i am looking to do it during the assignment, i have to name the row at the same time i input the value i can't name all the row later or name row by row later.

i mean you can add column byt doing df[["column name"]] <- value
isn't there an equivalent for rows ?

Comment: `rownames(mtcars)[5] <- "QUUX"`, allowing you to set one or many or all row names at once

Comment: But no, I don't know of a way to change a row name while adding columns to a frame